# How can I define a conditional "enlarge x limits"?

Tags: pgfplots, macros

I am plotting a series of graphs using a macro I've made (`\mygraph`, as given below). For some graphs I want all the data to be plotted with a bit of whitespace around it, which I get by using `enlarge x limits={abs=5mm}`. This is achieved in the below code for Figure 1. For other graphs (e.g. Figure 2) I want to just plot the data over a certain range, which I can achieve by specifying the `xmin` and `xmax` values, and by using `enlarge x limits=false`. How can go about implementing a conditional `enlarge x limits` in my macro such that it's set to false if either `xmin` or `xmax` are specified?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfplotsset{1Dgraph/.style={
    enlarge x limits={abs=5mm},
    % other settings that aren't relevant
}}

\newcommand{\mygraph}[4]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[1Dgraph,xmin=#3,xmax=#4,]
    \addplot[no markers, black] table[x index=0,y index=1] {#2};
    \addplot[no markers, red] table[x index=2,y index=3] {#2};
    \draw[dashed, gray] ({axis cs:#1,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,0}) -- ({axis cs:#1,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,1});
    \end{axis}      
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \mygraph{6}{data.txt}{}{}
    \caption{text}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \mygraph{6}{data.txt}{3}{10}
    \caption{text}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of research I managed to find the `ifthen` package, which gives me conditional statements. A working solution involved adding `\usepackage{ifthen}` to my preamble, then changing my `\mygraph` command to the following:

```
\newcommand{\mygraph}[4]{
    \ifthenelse{ \NOT\equal{#3}{} \OR \NOT\equal{#4}{} }
    { \pgfplotsset{1Dlimits/.style={enlarge x limits=false}} }
    { \pgfplotsset{1Dlimits/.style={}} }

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[1Dgraph,xmin=#3,xmax=#4,1Dlimits]
    \addplot[no markers, black] table[x index=0,y index=1] {#2};
    \addplot[no markers, red] table[x index=2,y index=3] {#2};
    \draw[dashed, gray] ({axis cs:#1,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,0}) -- ({axis cs:#1,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,1});
    \end{axis}      
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

This may be a very clunky solution, so if anyone has some better suggestions I'm keen to hear them.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it with `xifthen` package. `Ifthenelse` is checking whether the third argument i empty. If true it sets `\temp` to 5, if false sets it to 0. `\temp` is then used as a value of `enlarge x limits`. Hope this helps.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xifthen}

%\pgfplotsset{1Dgraph/.style={
%    enlarge x limits={abs=5mm},
%    % other settings that aren't relevant
%}}

\newcommand{\mygraph}[4]{
        \ifthenelse{\isempty{#3}}{\def \temp{5}}{\def \temp{0}} %assigning a value to /temp 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
    enlarge x limits={abs=\temp mm}, %enlarging the x limits by \temp value
    xmin=#3,xmax=#4,]
    \addplot[no markers, black] table[x index=0,y index=1] {#2};
    \addplot[no markers, red] table[x index=0,y index=2] {#2};
    \draw[dashed, gray] ({axis cs:#1,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,0}) -- ({axis cs:#1,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,1});
    \end{axis}      
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \mygraph{6}{data.txt}{0}{25}
    \caption{text}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \mygraph{6}{data.txt}{}{}
    \caption{text}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```